# I want to fixed scroll when the element's left change or change left reference to window.scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("layer1");
    var nowLeft = elmnt.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    nowLeft += nowLeft/100;
    elmnt.style.left = nowLeft + "px";
    console.log(nowLeft);
});
```

here is the code. I want to fixed user's scroll when the element is moving.
and I want to reference `window.scrollTop` when the element's left change.

scroll like thie page : http://www.rleonardi.com/interactive-resume/

Comment: Something like this? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Comment: Oh thank you but I found the solution.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm a little stupid guy.

```
elmnt.style.left = (base element's left)- window.scrollY + "px";
```

code like that. it can easily change the left despite scroll delay !

Comment: don't be hard on yourself. keep pushing :)